# Why is there no Zariski local trivial neighborhood of the origin?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm looking at the following post from MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/213231/is-a-morphism-whose-all-fibers-are-mathbfpn-a-projective-bundle/213235#213235

The purpose of the example in question is to find a morphism of varieties $\pi:X\to Y$ such that all fibers are $\Bbb P^n$, but $X$ is not a $\Bbb P^n$-bundle over $Y$.

We take $Y$ to be the variety cut out by $f(s,t)=t^2-s^2(1-s)$ in $\Bbb A^2$, and take $\nu:\Bbb A^1\to Y$ to be $\nu(u)=(1-u^2,u(1-u^2))$. Then let $V=\Bbb A^1\setminus\{1\}$, and take $X=V\times\Bbb P^n$, $\pi=\nu\circ\text{pr}_V:X\to Y$.

All fibers are $\Bbb P^n$ because the morphism $\nu|_V:V\to Y$ is a bijection, and the point in $Y$ which doesn't have a trivial Zariski neighborhood must be the origin, because this is the only singularity of $Y$.

My question is, how can I explicitly see that this point really doesn't have a trivial Zariski neighborhood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a Zariski locally trivial neighborhood, then $\pi$ has a section (locally near the origin). Composing it with the map $X \to V$, we get a section of the map $V \to Y$, which is absurd.